# Hold-one-out linear regression : a shortcut?

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, matrix

For a series of observations $(\vec{x}_i, y_i), i = 1 \cdots N$ from the linear model $Y =  \beta^T X + \epsilon$, the least squares estimate of $\beta$ is: $\hat{\beta} = (\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X})^{-1}(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Y})$. Fitted values can be obtained as $\hat{y}_i = \hat{\beta}^Tx_i$. However I would like the $\hat{y}_i$'s to be independent of the $i$th observation. That is, I would like $\hat{y}_i = \hat{\beta}_{(-i)}^T x_i$, where $\hat{\beta}_{(-i)}$ is calculated using only observations $1,2 \cdots i-1, i+1 \cdots N-1, N$. Doing N separate fits is computationally infeasible, and I suspect there is a shortcut: $\hat{\beta}$ and $\hat{\beta}_{(-i)}$ are very similar.

Any ideas? And does anyone know of a way in R to obtain such hold-one-out $\hat{y}$'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are fast ways to do those calculations.

if you look at `?influence.measures` several of the calculations there get you most of the way there.

Starting from either the `dffits` or `rstudent` functions, you ought to be able to back out the $\hat y_{(i)}$ values.

For example, the dffits function should implement [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFFITS) and the other components are pretty easily found.

If you investigate the content of the function `lm.influence` you might be able to do it a shorter way.

Comment: Thanks Glen_b. The best solution I've come up with involves using the \$coefficients matrix returned by lm.influences. \$coefficients contains the perturbations to the full fit coefficients, and with it the held-out $\hat{y}$'s can be calculated.